# Two maven versions required in pom.xml - what to do?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to build [JavaOCR](https://sourceforge.net/p/javaocr/source/ci/master/tree/) project with `mvn clean install`. There is used `maven-enforcer-plugin` in the `pom.xml` and there are two required Maven versions. (Or maybe I misunderstood something)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enforce-versions</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <requireMavenVersion>
                        <!--different rules for different issues-->
                        <!--3.3.x causes `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/aether/spi/connector/Transfer$State` which is caused by certain maven versions, see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound for details-->
                        <version>(,3.3)</version>
                        <!--3.2.x causes `No implementation for org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonConfigurator was bound.`-->
                        <version>(,3.2)</version>
                    </requireMavenVersion>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Currently I have installed maven 3.3.3 and it throws the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error (same as described in the comment in `pom.xml`), so I cannot build it.

My question is what version should I use to build the project successfully? Is it possible to use two maven versions simultaneously?

Comment: If you have read the linked wiki page you should be aware that it means that you are using old plugin version in the given build. The solution is to update the plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Maven's [Version Range Specification](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html) documentation, that's specifying a range, not a specific version. `(,3.2)` means anything less than version 3.2, so those two configurations are compatible: for example, use version 3.1.

This is reinforced by the comments in the pom file, which say that versions 3.2.x and 3.3.x cause errors, so don't use them.

#### See also

- [Version Range Specification](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html)